# hosting iscsi on smartos

Tags: iscsi, zfs, joyent, smartos

I am trying to get back into the unix game for some storage projects we have got going. We would love to use joyents smartos (based on illumos) for that.

Working with it is a real joy (setting up vms etc) but i can't get iscsi to work.

I would love to simply share a zfs device as an iscsi connection point but cant get it to work. I also cant get smb or nfs to work, but those properties at least exist and i am sure they would work.

The documentation i can find seems a little all-over-the-place with some old solaris, new solaris, illumos stuff etc. Which is understandable since it is such a new release though.

Does anybody have any pointers ?

I already tried

```
zfs set shareiscsi=on zones/name
```

which results in "unknown property". And its not listed in the zfs properties anyway.

I also tried

```
sbdadm create-lu /dev/zvol/rdsk/zones/
```

but this results in

```
sbdadm: unknown error
```

itadm also is not available and not service containing iscsi is listed in "svcs".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Creating an ISCSI Target**

enable the storage server and iscsi target server if necessary

```
svcadm enable stmf
svcadm enable -r svc:/network/iscsi/target:default
```

create a volume if necessary (sparse 10T in example)

```
zfs create -V 10T -s zones/iscsi
```

create a logical unit

```
sbdadm create-lu /dev/zvol/rdsk/zones/iscsi
```

Add a view on it (GUID is output by previous command or list-lu)

```
stmfadm add-view GUID
```

Create a target group to connect to (Choose a GROUPNAME and use an IP from the current server)

```
itadm create-tpg GROUPNAME IP
```

Create a target in this group

```
itadm create-target -t GROUPNAME
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is working with the February 2012 version of SmartOS. The Jan version was missing drivers.

BTW: When writing the Feb 2012 live image of SMARTOS to a usb stick it seemed to be authored incorrectly. The grub file was looking for files in a platform subfolder which did not exist. Simply create it and move the corresponding folder into it (see grub file)

Comment: You should edit your original answer to provide more information. Serverfault isn't a traditional forum. Read our [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) for more information on how it's different.

Comment: I do not have any buttons to edit it though :)